# How can spacetime be curved (flat) for an accelerated observer while it is flat (curved) for a non-accelerated observer?

Tags: general-relativity

If an observer accelerates through flat spacetime he observes a globally curved spacetime (as if gravity is present everywhere with a fixed and constant strength). If an observer accelerates in a curved spacetime (or, equivalently, if he follows a geodesic in the curved spacetime) he observes a locally flat spacetime. In the first case, spacetime is not really curved, while in the second it is. But how can the observer know (if he doesn't look out of the window)? Or just can't he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If an observer accelerates through flat spacetime he observes a globally curved spacetime

This is incorrect. Curvature is a tensor property of the spacetime. If the curvature is 0 (flat) in one reference frame then it is necessarily 0 in all other reference frames also.

For example, both standard Minkowski observers and Rindler observers agree that spacetime is flat. The curved coordinates of the Minkowski observer do not result in a curved spacetime.

> If an observer accelerates in a curved spacetime (or, equivalently, if he follows a geodesic in the curved spacetime) he observes a locally flat spacetime. In the first case, spacetime is not really curved, while in the second it is. But how can the observer know (if he doesn't look out of the window)? Or just can't he?

As you said, an observer in curved spacetime observes a locally flat spacetime. Therefore to observe curvature requires non-local measurements. Specifically, “locally flat” is a statement that refers to a first-order approximation. To detect curvature requires an experiment that is sensitive to second-order effects. This is what is meant by “local” in the context of the equivalence principle.

Comment: Ah! So curved Minkowski coordinates are not the same as curved spacetime?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The observer can measure the curvature tensor. Actually, in the first case an acceleration just represents a change of the reference system. The observer might experience acceleration which is represented in General Relativity by the Christoffel-symbols (the local derivatives of the metric tensor)  --- Christoffel-symbols are not a tensor by the way --- but the curvature tensor is zero (flat space) with an observer accelerated or not. A change of the reference system does not change the curvature of the given space. The curvature of a space is described by a tensor and a tensor cannot be set zero in all components by a change of the reference system. Equally a zero curvature tensor will not become non-zero by a change of the reference system.

An observer following a geodesics in a curved space might not experience any acceleration --- which means that the Christoffel-symbols are locally zero, but the curvature tensor won't become zero by such a change respectively any change   of the reference system.

Comment: So an accelerated observer (in flat spacetime) sees no curvature while experiencing acceleration (connected to the derivatives of the metric in flat spacetime), while an observer falling in a curved spacetime sees a curved spacetime while experiencing no acceleration (connected to the derivatives of the metric in curved spacetime)? But how will an observer know if the spacetime surrounding him is *really* curved or not?  How will he know if the metric is curved or not so he must use derivatives wrt to that metric?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder the presence of tidal forces is the signature dynamical signature of space-time curvature. At variance with forces, the gradient of forces cannot be eliminated locally by a change of reference frame.

Comment: @GiorgioP These forces are indeed not present inside the frame of the accelerated observer. Is this how he can tell that the spacetime isn't actually curved?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder tidal forces remain there. It is possible to make vanishing the gravitational force **locally**, not globally. Curvature is an intrinsic property of space-time. Some introductory books by Wheeler, like *A Journey into Gravity and Spacetime* provide a first, accurate introduction to the correct ideas, without the burden of complex math.

Comment: @GiorgioP Grazie! So if an observer accelerates through a globally flat spacetime, he can show that he's traveling through empty spacetime (instead of finding himself in a real gravitational field) by showing that he can't find tidal forces?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder yes. That is equivalent to the geometric statement that there is no curvature.